# Given 9 tiles, each can contain {0, 1, 2} how many states?

Tags: combinatorics

I know my question is simple, but I'm struggling to find an answer.

Given 9 inputs that could be either 0, 1 and 2, I was wondering how can I calculate the number of total different states possible.

For example, if I have 000000000, 000000001 and 000000002, these are 3 different states. And of course, 222221222 and 001001220 are different as well.

I tried to use combinatorial but I can't manage to have an assertive result.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

Do it from first principles, and start with a simpler problem. What if there were *two* tiles?

There are 3 ways to have the first thing. There are three ways to have the second thing. How many ways is that?

```
      0    1    2   
  0  00   01   02  
  1  10   11   12
  2  20   21   22
```

Can you do three tiles? Then four? Can you generalize?